# some questions about how to use momery by redis

Tags: memory, redis

I am rewriting the redis source code.

below:

```
c->argv = zmalloc(sizeof(robj*)*c->multibulklen);
...
c->argv[c->argc++] =
createStringObject(c->querybuf+pos,c->bulklen);
```

The part of code parses the parameters of a statement.for example: (set abc 123) the content of c->argv is c->argv[0] = set, c->argv[1] = abc, c->argv[2] = 123.
Storing the data into dict :

```
int dictAdd(dict *d, void *key, void *val)
{
    dictEntry *entry = dictAddRaw(d, key);

    if (!entry) return DICT_ERR;

    dictSetVal(d, entry, val);

    return DICT_OK;
}
```

key in dictAdd is "abc". val is "123".

The command--set abc 123  is finished.Then the momery used by c->argv is going to be freed.

```
void resetClient(redisClient *c) {
    redisCommandProc *prevcmd = c->cmd ? c->cmd->proc : NULL;
    freeClientArgv(c);
    DICT_NOTUSED(prevcmd);
    c->multibulklen = 0;
    c->bulklen = -1;
}
```

A error occurs to me when I run the second command, returning "abc" instead of "123".

I find that the memory address of "123" is replaced by "abc" included in "get abc".
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you "rewriting" it? It should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. because I don't add the object reference count.If the object reference count is 2,the memory is not going to be freed.